# Jquery shift generated button values in circular manner

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i am trying to make something fancy like this [create button and shift values](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D2sP74kzTHM), so far i have reached till here [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/zmrfzn/cj461kp6/5/)

```
$("#submit").click(function() {
    var n = $('#txtinp').val();
    if ($.isNumeric(n)) {
      //alert(n);
      var btns = $('#btns');
      for (var i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        btns.append('<input type="button" id="b' + i + '" value="' + i + '"/>');
      }
    } else {
      alert("enter a number");
    }
    $("input[type='button']").click(function(e) {
      var idClicked = e.target.id;
      //alert($(this).attr("value"));
      if (idClicked == 'b1' && $(this).attr("value") == 1) {
        $(this).prop('value', n);
        var lastBtn = 'b' + n;
        for (var i = n; i > 1; i--) {
          $('#b' + i).prop('value', i - 1);
        }
      } else {
        var lastBtn = 'b' + n;
        for (var i = n; i >= 1; i--) {
          if ('b' + i == 'b1' && 'b' + n == n) {
            $('#b' + i).prop('value', i);
          } else {
            $('#b' + i).prop('value', i - 1);
          }
        }
      }
    });

});
```

I am able to shift only once if clicked on very first created button, but the function or event does not work on second and further clicks. I have no prior Jquery experience, what is that i am doing wrong here?

please do not down vote if the question is too stupid.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one possible solution:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#submit").click(function() {
    var n = $('#txtinp').val();
    if ($.isNumeric(n)) {
      var btns = $('#btns').empty();
      for (var i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        btns.append($('<button>').text(i));
      }
    } else {
      alert("enter a number");
    }

    $("#btns button").click(function(e) {
      var buttons = $('#btns button');
      buttons.each(function () {
        var currentValue = parseInt($(this).text());
        var newValue = currentValue - 1;
        if (newValue === 0) {
          newValue = buttons.length;
        }
        $(this).text(newValue);
      });
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="txtinp" />
<input type="button" id="submit" value="Submit" />
<div id="btns">

</div>
```

Comment: each function looks great. you just solved my entire problem.can you please explain why my code worked only for 1 click ?

Comment: @ZameerFouzan For me, your code didn't even work for one click. (If I clicked the first button, it replaced it with a 5 but didn't change anything else. If I clicked other buttons, it didn't seem to do anything.)

Comment: @ZameerFouzan I couldn't really understand what you were trying to do in your code, so I wrote my own from scratch. Sorry!

Comment: okay , thanks for your solution , i will try to rebuild mine again in a different way. :) also please upvote my question, so that i get some reps :D